# Wordpress blog theme (small template) not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming, woothemes

We recently bought the wordpress sandy template(sandy-light theme) for our blog site. We are facing some troubles in changing the theme for home page. Currently the homepage is having the default template(Blog Big Template) and we want to change the homepage alone to look like the Blog Small Template design and we couldn't achieve it for some reason. Also if we create a new page and select the Blog Small Template as its default template, the left side thumbnail is not appearing whereas it appears in the Blog Big Template.
and Header-image upload not working

Demo website for the Theme: http://wopethemes.com/demo/sandy/blog-small/

Could you please help us overcome this issue? Any help would be greatful.

Comment: http://support.envato.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/472/85/wordpress-theme-submission-requirements ........... These might help